# Ember binding self property

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How to create view class and bind property from self in Ember.js(1.0) ?
Something like this:

```
SomeClass = Ember.View.extend
  someProp: true
  createChildView: ->
   OtherView.create
    somePropBinding: 'this.someProp'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `parentView` to get access to the `parentView`'s properties should work:

Example:

```
App.MyView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
  someProp: true,
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var viewClass = App.SomeView.create();
    this.pushObject(viewClass);
  }
});
```

Then you could use `Ember.computed.alias('...)` to create a binding:

```
App.SomeView = Ember.View.extend({
  anotherProp: Ember.computed.alias('parentView.someProp'),
  didInsertElement: function() {
    console.log('anotherProp: '+this.get('anotherProp'));
  }
});
```

*sorry for not coffescriptifying the code :)*

Working [example](http://jsbin.com/aVoLiS/3/edit).

Hope it helps.